# I'm trying to install ImageMagick via HomeBrew and the Brew Doctor is giving me the following error. Any advice?

Tags: download, imagemagick, installation, homebrew, configure

Warning: "config" scripts exist outside your system or Homebrew directories.
`./configure` scripts often look for *-config scripts to determine if
software packages are installed, and what additional flags to use when
compiling and linking.

Having additional scripts in your path can confuse software installed via
Homebrew if the config script overrides a system or Homebrew provided
script of the same name. We found the following "config" scripts:

```
/opt/sm/pkg/active/bin/curl-config
/opt/sm/pkg/active/bin/ncurses5-config
/opt/sm/pkg/active/bin/ncursesw5-config
/opt/sm/pkg/active/bin/pkg-config
/opt/sm/pkg/active/bin/xml2-config
/opt/sm/pkg/active/bin/xslt-config
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit your PATH to remove those config scripts. They are likely to be added somewhere in ~/.bashrc if an installer added them.

If you have MacPorts or Fink installed, it won't hurt to remove them as they often interfere with Homebrew.